# How to make form topmost to the application only?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am making excel add-in in which clicking on menu item or toolbar button, Form opened. I have set form's topmost to true but it remain topmost to all applications of windows xp. I just need to remain topmost to Microsoft Excel only.

I have choosed project in Visual Studio 2008, in Excel ->2003.

Please tell me how to do that with any way ........

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set your Form's owner to be the Microsoft Excel window.  In Windows [owned windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28VS.85%29.aspx#owned_windows) are always displayed above their owner.  Dialogs and things like the search box in Excel are owned windows, which is what keeps them displayed above their owner.

There are a couple of ways you can set a Form's parent:

1. The [Form.Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property (although the owner has to be another form)
2. Use the [Form.Show(IWin32Window owner)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) overload.  (See this [blog post](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/23/465.aspx) for how translate an window handle to an IWin32Window).
3. Use [SetWindowLong()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the GWLP_HWNDPARENT parameter.
4. Use [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) as Mikael Svenson suggested.

This does require you to know the Excel applications window handle.

Comment: Don't forget to set `TopMost` to `False` if you're using `Form.Owner`!

Answer (score 1):

[Edit - changed code]

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

void func()
{
   Form1 f = new Form1();
   SetParent(f.Handle, (IntPtr)ThisAddIn.ExcelApplication.Hwnd);
   f.Show();
}
```