# How to keep a dialog on top of application

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin

I'm currently working on a little outlook-addin. My plugin opens a dialog (*System.Windows.Forms.Form*).

I'd like to keep the dialog on top of outlook, so I tried the **TopMost**, but that keeps the dialog on top of all applications.

I'd like the dialog to be on top **when outlook is the active application**, how can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to **Dmitry** and **kallocain** I could solve this issue. I want to outline my resulting solution:

In the *TabCalendarRibbon* class of my Outlook plugin I have an event method for activating my dialog, there I used the code from kallocain to get the window handle:

```
Explorer explorer = Context as Explorer;
IntPtr explorerHandle = (IntPtr)0;

if (explorer != null)
{
    IOleWindow window = explorer as IOleWindow;
    if (window != null)
    {
        window.GetWindow(out explorerHandle);
    }
}
```

As described in kollacains answer, I had to add the OLE interop assembly. I used the explorer handle to *Show* my dialog:

```
var dlg = new NewEntryDialog();
dlg.Show(new WindowWrapper(explorerHandle));
```

As you might notice, I could not use the window handle directly but had to implement a tiny wrapper that implements *IWin32Window*. For this I followed a description I found via the previous answer Dmitry linked to. I simply copied the following code:

```
public class WindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
    public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
    {
        _hwnd = handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return _hwnd; }
    }

    private IntPtr _hwnd;
}
```

And voila, it works pretty much as I expected. It would be even better if the dialog was only active as long as I am on the calendar ribbon, but that is something for another day. BTW, pretty much code for the result, I think...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613494/how-to-make-form-topmost-to-the-application-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Akrem noted, see [How to make form topmost to the application only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613494/how-to-make-form-topmost-to-the-application-only). To get the HWND of an Outlook explorer  object (e.g. Application.ActiveExplorer), cast it to IOleWindow and call IOleWindow.GetWindow().

Comment: I will definitly rate this as answer as soon as I find out how to get the window handle. I use the Outlook.Application object to call ActiveExplorer() but I cannot cast the result to IOleWindow. The interface is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry answer is correct. You just have to add a reference to "Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll" (can be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies).

```
Explorer explorer = control.Context as Explorer;
if (explorer != null)
{
   IOleWindow window = explorer as IOleWindow;
   if (window != null)
   {
      IntPtr explorerHandle;
      window.GetWindow(out explorerHandle);
   }
}
```